# C Programming: Linked LIst Swapping Position of Nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been having a lot of trouble lately with my programming homework. I have no clue how to go about the swap function. I'm not even sure if I correctly coded in two other functions. I need some guidance on how to this because whenever I try to do anything in the swap function, I keep getting a "request for member in something not a structure or union.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "StudentRecord.h"
#include "StudentRecordNode.h"

void parseFile(char* filename, struct student_record_node** head);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

struct student_record_node* head = student_record_allocate();


parseFile(argv[1], &head);
printf("Before sorting...\n");
printNodeList(head);
printf("Sorting by age...\n");
sort(&head, *ageComparator);
printNodeList(head);

}

void parseFile(char* filename, struct student_record_node** head)
{
int i = 0;
struct student_record_node* newNode = *head;
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Input file could not be read\n");
    exit(1);
}

while(1)
{
    if(newNode != *head)
    {
        newNode = student_record_allocate();
        appendNode(*head, newNode);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %d", newNode->record_->first_name_, newNode->record_->last_name_, 
&newNode->record_->student_id_, &newNode->record_->student_age_);

    if(newNode == *head)
    {
        newNode = NULL;
    }
    if(feof(fp))
    {
        break;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

My main.c

Then my StudentRecordNode.h

```
#ifndef STUDENTRECORDNODE_H
#define STUDENTRECORDNODE_H
#include "StudentRecord.h"

struct student_record_node
{
    struct student_record* record_;
    struct student_record_node* next_;
    struct student_record_node* prev_;
};

struct student_record_node* student_record_allocate()
{
    struct student_record_node* newNode;
    newNode = calloc(1, sizeof(struct student_record_node));
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory allocated for newNode");
            exit(1);
    }

    newNode->record_ = calloc(1, sizeof(struct student_record));
    if (newNode->record_ == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory allocated for record_");
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->next_ = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void appendNode(struct student_record_node* head, struct student_record_node* newNode)
{
    int i = 1;
    struct student_record_node* current = head;

    while(i)
    {
        if (current->next_ == NULL)
        {
            current->next_ = newNode;
            i = 0;
        }
        current = current->next_;
    }
}

void printNode(struct student_record_node* node)
{
    printf("struct student_record_node:\n");
    printf("\tStudent first name: %s\n", node->record_->first_name_);
    printf("\tStudent last name: %s\n", node->record_->last_name_);
    printf("Student id: %d\n", node->record_->student_id_);
    printf("Student age: %d\n", node->record_->student_age_);
}

void printNodeList(struct student_record_node* head)
{
    struct student_record_node* current = head;
    while(current->next_ != NULL)
    {
        printNode(current);
        current = current->next_;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(struct student_record_node** node1, struct student_record_node** node2)
{
    struct student_record_node* ptr;
    struct student_record_node* ptr2;

    ptr = *node1;
    ptr2 = *node2;
    if (ptr == ptr2)
    return;

    ptr->next_ = ptr2->next_;
    ptr2->prev_ = ptr->prev_;

    if (ptr->next_ != NULL)
        ptr->next_->prev_ = ptr;

    if (ptr2->prev_ != NULL)
        ptr2->prev_->next_ = ptr2;

    ptr2->next_ = ptr;
    ptr->prev_ = ptr2;

}


void sort(struct student_record_node** recordsHead, int (*compare_fcn)(struct student_record_node*, struct student_record_node*))
{
    int swapped, i;
    struct student_record_node* ptr;
    struct student_record_node* ptr2 = NULL;

    if (*recordsHead == NULL)
        return;

do
{

    swapped = 0;
    ptr = *recordsHead;

    while(ptr->next_ != ptr2)
    {
        if(compare_fcn(ptr, ptr->next_) > 0)
        {
            swap(&ptr, &ptr->next_);
            if(ptr == *recordsHead)
            {
            (*recordsHead) = ptr->prev_;
            }
        swapped = 1;
        }

    else
    {
        ptr = ptr->next_;
    }
    }
    ptr2 = ptr;
}
while(swapped);
}

int ageComparator(struct student_record_node* node1, struct student_record_node* node2)
{
    int a = 1;
    struct student_record_node* ptr;
    struct student_record_node* ptr2;

    ptr = node1;
    ptr2 = node2;   

    if (ptr->record_->student_age_ > ptr2->record_->student_age_&&ptr->next_ != NULL)
    return a; 

    else
    return 0;

}

int idComparator(struct student_record_node* node1, struct student_record_node* node2)
{
    int a = 1;

    if (node1->record_->student_id_ > node2->record_->student_id_)
    {
        return a;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void student_record_node_deallocate(struct student_record_node* node)
{
    struct student_record_node* temp;
    temp = node;
    free(temp->record_);
    free(temp);
}

void freeNodeList(struct student_record_node* head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        student_record_node_deallocate(head);
        head = head->next_;
    }
}

#endif
```

Please tell me if there is anything wrong with the functions. I think the only ones that are problematic are the swap, sort, and ageComparator functions (ignore the idComparator). Thank you.

Edit: I was stupid. I figured out the error I kept getting. My program almost works now. The problem is that when I sort by age and id now that I retyped them, it will print them sorted. However, it seems to have pushed up all of the elements up one position as the first node is now completely NULL. All the information is 0 or NULL, but it is clear that all the elements that are filled with information are in the list.

https://puu.sh/vvlVr/96605bcc35.png

Here is what I mean. Any help is appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: Not checking the result of `fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %...` leads to trouble.  `if(feof(fp))` is too late.

Comment: I seem to not have had any trouble with that at all throughout the entire program.